# Where are info document files in Mac or in Linux, and how can I install some missing info files?

Tags: gnu, gnu-coreutils, info

I wanted read coreutils info, but I could not find it. Now, I wonder where the info documents in my computer (mac or linux). I want to know how I can install info files.

Thank you,

SangChul

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you entered `info coreutils` on the command line, which returned the info top directory instead of the coreutils info page? In that case, here is what I would do (on ubuntu 15.10, and probably on any GNU/Linux OS).

Download the coreutils info document from the gnu project:

```
wget http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.info.tar.gz
```

Extract the (compressed) tar archive that you downloaded:

```
tar xf coreutils.info.tar.gz
```

Re-compress the resulting info file:

```
gzip coreutils.info
```

Prepare the resulting file with the right attributes:

```
chmod 644 coreutils.info.gz
sudo chown root:root coreutils.info.gz
```

and move it into the info directory:

```
sudo mv coreutils.info.gz /usr/share/info
```

Now, the command

```
info coreutils
```

should work.

If you want to have a hypertext link to coreutils in the info top page then do:

```
sudo install-info --info-dir=/usr/share/info --info-file=/usr/share/info/coreutils.info.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this somewhere that I do not know where it was.

```
strings `which info` | grep /info
```

This would print out some default info directories that had been compiled with the info command. One can also export a shell variable called INFOPATH with info directories you want.